# Parse saveInBackgroundError - Expected string, but got array

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm new to Parse and am trying to save a new row to my table (on Android). 
I've made sure that all my columns that I want to add to are of type String, as well as my objects.

Here is the code that I use to save it to the database:

```
        ParseObject accountObj = new ParseObject("networks");

        accountObj.add("token", token);
        accountObj.add("parse_user", parseUser);
        accountObj.add("type", "facebook");
        accountObj.add("fb_profile_url", profileUrl);

        accountObj.saveInBackground(); // expected type string but got array
```

Could somebody please explain what is going on? I've tried deleting the class and starting fresh, but it just gives me the same answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what ParseObject.add() does, but the docs say to use ParseObject.put() instead.

From the docs:

```
ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
gameScore.put("score", 1337);
gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
gameScore.saveInBackground();
```

Source: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-saving

This could solve your issue, as perhaps the .add() function is used to add objects to an array (hence the array error).